# php error <b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected ':' in

Tags: php, actionscript

I am using Flash and PHP to create a JPG.  I have the Flash and PHP working as expected on my localhost server.  When I upload to server I get the following error:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in
>   **/home/carlosrg/public_html/mysubdomain/image.php** on line
>   **6**

And the code:

```
<?PHP
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$targetFilename = date(‘YmdHis’).’_’.mt_rand().’.jpg’;

$serverpath = ‘http://www.mysubdomain.myserver.com';
$directoryPath = ‘/newimagesfolder/‘;

$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$directoryPath.$targetFilename;

if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'userfile' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $target_path ) ) 
{
    echo $serverpath.$directoryPath.$targetFilename;
} 
else
{
     echo "error";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You seem to be using odd apostrophes. You need to use `'`, and not the `‘` ones - are those from Word?

Comment: Curly quotes; *beautiful* yet **deadly**.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong quotes. `‘` should be normal single quotes `'`. What's odd is you have them correct elsewhere in this code. Looks like a probable cut-and-paste error to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have used  `‘`, you need use single or double `'`' or `"`  quotes

```
 $targetFilename = date("YmdHis")."_".mt_rand().".jpg";

 $serverpath = "http://www.mysubdomain.myserver.com";
 $directoryPath = "/newimagesfolder/";
```

Comment: That's not a backtick. it's a typographic/curly quote, which is something completely different. OP was probably using something like Word to edit the code.

Comment: That was it.  I was trying to be quick and opened the PHP file in a text editor and the ticks got messed up.  THANK YOU, ALL!  I'll try to be more creative with my next issue.